# Error in aspx page when using class inside of span tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Sorry about the ambiguous title but it is the best I could do.

I am getting the following error

> Argument type 'object' is not assignable to parameter type 'int'

The line that is referenced is:

```
<span class = '<%#BindPageNumberClass(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem")) %>' onclick="dtpaging_Page_Selected('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem")%>');">
```

This line produces the red squiggle that is indicative of an error in the first portion

```
<span class = '<%#BindPageNumberClass(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem")).....
```

So naturally I thought I should convert this line to Int32 but sadly enough it did not work and gave me almost the same error.  I searched the internet and tried many failed attempts at fixing this error.

Has anyone else ran into this issue?  What I find perplexing is that only the first part of the line is erroring out when the rest of the line (which appears to be the exact same code) is not erroring out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [return value of `DataBinder.Eval` is an object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.110).aspx). Assuming your `BindPageNumberClass` takes an `int` as it's parameter, you'll need to cast the return of the eval call to `int` using `(int)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem")`:

```
<span class='<%#BindPageNumberClass((int)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem")) %>'
    onclick="dtpaging_Page_Selected('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem")%>');">
```

Comment: Seriously it was that easy.......Thank you as soon as I can I will accept this answer